# EF Core adding Parent and Child in same transaction

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I have standard parent/children design:

```
class Parent {
    Guid Id;
    List<Child> Children;

    public Parent() {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Children = new List<Child>();
    }

    public AddChild(Child ch) {
        this.Children.Add(ch);
    }
}

class Child {
    Guid Id;

    public Child() {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

My mapping is like this:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Parent> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Parents");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder.HasMany(p => p.Children)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey("ParentId");
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Child> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Children");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
}
```

Now, in my service method (add child to parent, create parent in case of not existing in system):

```
var parent = await _parentsRepository.GetParent(parentId);

if (parent == null)
{
    parent = new Parent();
    await _parentsRepository.AddAsync(customerMembersip); // adding parent to context, with empty Children collection, but not saving to DB yet
}

parent.AddChild(new Child()); // this make this new Child in Parent object to be in state "Modified", but in fact should be in state "Added". Why?

// save changes here
```

In other words, why adding child to parent (parent just added to context) makes child being seen as **Modified**? But if I get the parent from repo and it is immediately in context, and then I add child, then child is seen as **Added**.

**Edit:**

It may be due to fact, that Id (of type Guid) is generated in C# code, thus EF "thinks" it is existing entity, thus it marks is as "Modified". But I don't quite understand why, in case of Parent already exists in DB (the _parentsRepository returns actual entity)

Comment: (1)  Please rename your "Id"'s to diambiguate them.  ParentId (or ParentKey) and ChildId (or ChildKey.  (2) I think you need to add reciprocal relationship.  (on the Child.configure)  example:            this.HasRequired(t => t.Parent)
                .WithMany(t => t.Children)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentKey);

Comment: To continue.  Your Child object needs a property like "Parent MyParent {get;set}".  Then on your method "public AddChild(Child ch)", you need to add a new line .. something like "ch.MyParent = this; "

Comment: I'll try this approach, but it violates DDD as from DDD in my business case I simply don't need two-way relation in my model. Adding bit of complexity just because EF doesn't like "pregenerated Guid" doesn't sound right for me.

Comment: EF is all about "reciprocal" relationships, at least in my experience.  If you wanted to (only) add a single Child, how would the db know what the FK to the parent would be? (without the "Parent MyParent {get;set}" property on the Child?)

Comment: Reciprocity is defined on mapping (Configure files) level. Per my experience it is not needed to have 2-way relationship within your domain model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.

In Asp.net core 3.0 (thus EF Core 3.0) you need to change mapping of `Child` from:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Child> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Children");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
}
```

to:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Child> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Children");
    builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever(); // change is here!
}
```

Hope it helps others.